# SWING actionPerformed never called

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

in this code i have a jbutton with an ActionListener added to it (BoutonListener) but when the button is clicked, the method actionPerformed() is never called.
I'm new with SWING so i'm might have overlooked something important, but i don't what i missed here, help please.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Plateau{
Fenetre f;
Modele mo;
CaseListener co;
BoutonListener li; 

public Plateau(int dim){
this.f = new Fenetre(dim);
this.mo = new Modele();
this.co = new CaseListener();
this.li = new BoutonListener();
}

private class Fenetre extends JFrame{

public JPanel principale; // partie informative
public JPanel grille; // grille de jeu
public Case [][] tabs; 
public int dim;

private static final String bf1 = "bf1.png";
private static final String mf1  = "mf1.png";
private static final String nf1 = "nf1.png";

private static final String bf2 = "bf2.png";
private static final String mf2  = "mf2.png";
private static final String nf2 = "nf2.png";

Container c = this.getContentPane();

JButton b = new JButton("bon"); // boutons pour ajouter les fantomes
JButton m = new JButton("mauvais");

public Fenetre(int dim){
this.dim = dim;
this.tabs = new Case[this.dim][this.dim];

c.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
JPanel principale = new JPanel();
JPanel grille = new JPanel();
JLabel lab = new JLabel("Test");
principale.add(lab);

b.addActionListener(li);   
m.addActionListener(li);

principale.add(b);
principale.add(m);

c.add(principale);
grille.setBackground(Color.black);
c.add(grille);

this.setVisible(true);
this.setSize(600,300);
this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
this.setTitle("Ghosts");

grille.setLayout(new GridLayout(this.dim, this.dim));

for(int i = 0; i < this.dim ; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < this.dim ; j++){

// création de toutes les cases

    tabs[i][j] = new Case();
    tabs[i][j].addMouseListener(co);

    tabs[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    grille.add(tabs[i][j]);

    if( (i == 0 || i == this.dim-1) && ( j == 0 || j == this.dim-1  )){ // cases sorties
        tabs[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }

    }
}
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void miseAJour(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < this.dim ; i++){
    for(int j = 0 ; j < this.dim ; j++){
        tabs[i][j].repaint();
    }
    }
}

}



private class Modele{

    int total = 0;
    int bj1 = 0;
    int mj1 = 0;
    int bj2 = 0;
    int mj2 = 0;



    public Case prochainePlace(){
        for(int i = 0; i < f.dim ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < f.dim ; j++){

            if(j !=0 && j != f.dim - 1 && (i > f.dim-3 || (i < 2)) ){  // fantomes J1
            if(f.tabs[i][j].getFantome() == null){
                total++; 
                return f.tabs[i][j];

            }
            }
        }

        }

        return null;
    }

    public boolean remplissable(){
        return((bj1 + bj2 + mj1 + mj2) < (f.dim *2)-4 );
    }

    public void ajoutFantome(Case c , boolean bon){
        if(total <= 8){
        if(bon && bj1 < 4){
            c.setFantome(new Fantome(true, Fenetre.bf1 , 2 ));

            c.repaint();
            bj1++;
        }
        if(!bon && mj1 < 4){
            c.setFantome(new Fantome(false,Fenetre.mf1 , 1 ));

            c.repaint();
            mj1++;
        }
        }
        else{
        if(bon && bj2 < 4 ){
            c.setFantome(new Fantome(true, Fenetre.bf2 , 2 ));

            c.repaint();
            bj2++;
        }
        if(!bon && mj2 < 4){
            c.setFantome(new Fantome(false, Fenetre.mf2 , 2 ));

            c.repaint();
            mj2++;
        }
        }
    }

    }

private class BoutonListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("fonction called");
        if(mo.remplissable()){

        if(e.getSource() == f.b){
            mo.ajoutFantome(mo.prochainePlace(), true);
            f.miseAJour();
        }
        else{
            mo.ajoutFantome(mo.prochainePlace(), false);
            f.miseAJour();
        }
        }
    }

}


private class CaseListener implements MouseListener{


    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){

    }   

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){

    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){

    }

    }

}
```

Comment: If you indent your code properly people are more likely to bother trying to read it.

Comment: Could you maybe shorten the code to only contain your problem? It is harder to help the more code there is.

Comment: And translate your code to english maybe? Please create a [Runnable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the minimum code to reproduce the issue, so we can copy-paste it and see what's happening.

Comment: @Frakcool Come on. There's enough info here. I have one question for you though: Is the `Case` class a `Button` or `JButton`? D'abord, en francais, est-ce que votre `Case` est aussi un bouton?

Comment: @Zizouz212 there's more than enough. I'm asking OP to provide **only** the necessary code, no more, no less. But ok, anyway I'll try to read it...

Comment: Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signify that this is solved. You also get 2 reputation points for doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Note your Plateaue constructor:

```
public Plateau(int dim) {
    this.f = new Fenetre(dim);  // (A)
    this.mo = new Modele();
    this.li = new BoutonListener();  // (B)
}
```

You create your Fenetre JFrame at line (A), and this is where you add your ActionListener, li, to the JButtons, but you assign an ActionListener to the li variable at (B) **after** you've created the JFrame. So you're really adding null references as ActionListeners to the JButtons with in your Fenetre constructor:

```
    public Fenetre(int dim) {

        // .... <deleted code>

        // li is null here!
        b.addActionListener(li);
        m.addActionListener(li);
```

One Solution: Reverse this.

```
public Plateau(int dim) {
    this.li = new BoutonListener();  // call this first
    this.f = new Fenetre(dim);  
    this.mo = new Modele();
}
```

Now the JButtons will get ActionListeners instances and not null references.

Note, a better more OOP-compliant solution might be to give Fenetre its own `addBoutonListener(ActionListener l)` method, one where you add the listeners to the JButtons, so that your Plateau constructor code could instead be:

```
public Plateau(int dim) {
    this.f = new Fenetre(dim);  
    this.mo = new Modele();
    f.addBoutonListener(new BoutonListener());
}
```

And within Fenetre, you could have:

```
    public void addBoutonListener(BoutonListener btnListener) {
        b.addActionListener(btnListener);
        m.addActionListener(btnListener);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now. Indeed the way you do it seems better, i think i'll change it.
Sorry for the indentation and french in the code, i'll make sure to post a clean question next time.